# SQL Server "FOR XML" output from queries joining two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xsd

I'm new to the "FOR XML" feature in SQL Server.  I am using SQL Server 2012.

I have two tables,  Word and Word_Expansion.

Sample data:

table [Word]:

```
WordOID   Word
-------   ----    
      1   PIPE
      2   WIRE
```

table [Word_Expansion]:

```
WEOID  fk_WordOID  Word_Expansion
-----  ----------  --------------
    1          2             COAX
    2          2    SPEAKER CABLE
    3          1          CONDUIT
```

Now, I would like to produce XML something like:

```
<expansion>
  <sub>WIRE</sub>
  <sub>SPEAKER CABLE</sub>
</expansion>
<expansion>
  <sub>PIPE</sub>
  <sub>CONDUIT</sub>
</expansion>
```

I have come close with various efforts at crafting XML FOR statements, but I just can't seem to grasp what it is that I need to do to get these two tables mashed into the right XML output.  I'll be digging further into XML FOR syntax, but if you have a moment and know this well...

Does anyone have any pointers as to what I should try?

Comment: Is your output correct? It seems like there should be a <sub>COAX</sub> in the top <expansion> element. Also for the sake of formatting can you fix the close tag on the "SPEAKER CABLE"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you:

**SQL:**

```
SELECT Word Sub,      
        (      
             SELECT Word_Expansion  AS Sub   
             FROM Word_Expansion WE
             WHERE WE.fk_WordOID = W.WordOID 
             FOR XML PATH(''), type 
        )      
FROM Word W
FOR XML PATH ('Expansion')
```

**XML Output:**

```
<Expansion>
  <Sub>Pipe</Sub>
  <Sub>CONDUIT</Sub>
</Expansion>
<Expansion>
  <Sub>Wire</Sub>
  <Sub>COAX</Sub>
  <Sub>SPEAKER CABLE</Sub>
</Expansion>
```

Although i'm not sure why you want Word.Word to be classified as "Sub"? 
Shouldn't this instead be the parent of Word_Expansion (which should be sub?)

EDIT: I found this link quite useful when looking into FOR XML and nested queries [Nested FOR XML](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/08/26/nested-xml-results-from-sql-server-with-for-xml-path/)

Comment: Argh, you beat me, mine looks a little different, but same principle. The WE.WordOID on you subquery criteria need to be fk_WordOID. There is no WordOID in the Word_Expansion table. Otherwise this is perfect. Kudos.

Comment: Quite right, good spot! Indeed, same in principle but I think it is good for the OP to see different methodologies that meet the same goal.

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is the creation of a Thesaurus XML file for use in MSSQL 2012. I have those two tables, one that contains a "root word" that ties to all the syns in the second table. Here is the format of the MSSQL XML file: --    <thesaurus xmlns="x-schema:tsSchema.xml">
--      <diacritics = false/>
--        <expansion>
--            <sub>Internet Explorer</sub>
--            <sub>IE</sub>
--            <sub>IE5</sub>
--        </expansion>
--        <expansion>
--            <sub>run</sub>
--            <sub>jog</sub>
--        </expansion>
--    </thesaurus>

Comment: Using either of these was the trick that I was looking for.  I added a [ , Root ('thesaurus') ] to the end, which formed the structure that MSSQL 2012 is expecting, less one element.  I am able to edit the result to tweak the root and to add the missing element under the root.  The meat was to run this query against a large relationship.Most of the XML FOR is making sense, but I was having a hard time wrapping my mind around putting in the sub-query with the proper path.  I want to thank both of you for the help.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is mine... I upvoted the first post because his was fastest, but it does it a little different so I figured it couldn't hurt to add mine...

```
With    groupedWords
As
(
        Select  WordOID, 
                Word
        From    Word
        Union   
        Select  fk_WordOID, Word_Expansion
        From    Word_Expansion
)
Select (Select  s.word As sub 
        From    groupedWords s 
        Where   s.WordOID = n.WordOID 
        For     Xml Path(''), Type)
From    groupedWords n
Group   By n.WordOID
For     Xml Path('expansion')
```

Comment: Your version enlightens me that much more. Thank you.