# How to insert element after root node in multiple xml output via FOR XML in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, nested, output

I'm try use "FOR XML" feature in SQL Server. I am using SQL Server 2008 Express. I need XML results with SQL Server.

I have two tables, dbo.document and dbo.items.

Sample data:

First table [Document]:

```
     ID   info1  info2
-------   ----   ----- 
      1    11      22
```

Second table [Items]:

```
     ID   nvarchar1   nvarchar2   nvarchar3  docId
-------   ----        ----       ----        ----
      1    d          e          f            1
      2   dd          ee         ff           1
```

Based on [Create single XML from SQL Server multiple tables query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887369/create-single-xml-from-sql-server-multiple-tables-query) , [Get nested XML output sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18785693/get-nested-xml-output-sql-server) and [SQL Server “FOR XML” output from queries joining two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718026/sql-server-for-xml-output-from-queries-joining-two-tables)
my code is:

```
SELECT     TOP (1)Document.info1, Document.info2,
(SELECT     TOP (3)
nvarchar1,
nvarchar2,
nvarchar3
FROM         Items 
WHERE Items.docId = Document.id
FOR XML PATH ('myitem'), TYPE)
FROM         Document
order by id desc
FOR XML PATH ('List'), ROOT ('myroot')
```

And result is:

```
 <myroot>    
      <List>
      <info1>11</info1>
      <info2>22</info2> 
        <myitem>
          <nvarchar1>d</nvarchar1>
          <nvarchar2>e</nvarchar2>
          <nvarchar3>f</nvarchar3>
        </myitem>
        <myitem>
          <nvarchar1>dd</nvarchar1>
          <nvarchar2>ee</nvarchar2>
          <nvarchar3>ff</nvarchar3>
        </myitem>
      </List>
    </myroot>
```

**But I want xml in following format:** (insert elements info1, info2 directly after myroot)

```
<myroot>    
<info1>11</info1>
<info2>22</info2>   
      <List>
        <myitem>
          <nvarchar1>d</nvarchar1>
          <nvarchar2>e</nvarchar2>
          <nvarchar3>f</nvarchar3>
        </myitem>
        <myitem>
          <nvarchar1>dd</nvarchar1>
          <nvarchar2>ee</nvarchar2>
          <nvarchar3>ff</nvarchar3>
        </myitem>
      </List>
    </myroot>
```

Does anyone have any solutions for this case?  Thanks a lot.
Note: Next variant:  info1,info 2 will be stored in third table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the ROOT('List') to the nested select statement, then set the PATH of the outer select to '' like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
        Document.info1
        , Document.info2
        ,(
            SELECT TOP (3)
                    nvarchar1
                    ,nvarchar2
                    ,nvarchar3
                FROM Items
                WHERE
                    Items.docId = Document.id
                FOR XML PATH ('myitem'),ROOT ('List'), TYPE
        )
    FROM Document
    ORDER BY ID DESC
    FOR XML PATH (''), ROOT ('myroot')
```

That should work.

Comment: Yes, thank you @RicGuerrero. I have one more question: what If I need put <myitem><nvarchar1></nvarchar1>...<myitem/> between next leve like <myitem_list><myitem><nvarchar1></nvarchar1>...</myitem></myitem_list> ----> so the final result will be **<myroot><List><myitem_list><myitem><nvarchar1></nvarchar1>...</myitem></myitem_list></List></myroot> ?**